# Is there a better way to read unzipped data into a slice?

Tags: go

I'm reading gzip data from a http request like this:

```
gzr, err := gzip.NewReader(resp.Body)
handle(err)
```

And then conservatively allocating a slice for the unzipped data.

```
cl := resp.Header.Get("Content-Length")
icl, err := strconv.Atoi(cl)
handle(err)
ubs := make([]byte, icl*3)
```

And finally trimming the slice after reading

```
_, err = gzr.Read(ubs)
ubs = bytes.TrimRightFunc(ubs, sliceFunc)
```

Is there a better way to do this ?

Comment: Also, `io.Reader` allows a reader to return as much or as little data as it wants to on each `Read` call; it's fully allowed to return one byte per call if it wants. `gzip.Reader` doesn't say otherwise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For starters, `.Read` returns the numbers of bytes read, so you can do something like:

```
n, err = gzr.Read(ubs)
ubs = ubs[:n]
```

Also you can use a `bytes.Buffer` pool and do something like:

```
buf := getBufferFromPool()
io.Copy(buf, gzr)
```

Comment: Not sure how I missed the returned number of bytes read. The advantage of bytes.Buffer is it needs no initialization ?

Comment: You have to initialise the buffer. The advantage to using a pool is that you don't 'throw it away' (generate garbage) after use - you just reset the contents, return it to the pool and get it again. Initialisation is therefore a 'startup time cost' only. A package like https://github.com/oxtoacart/bpool provides a simple pool implementation.